# Two ways for finding the basis and dim of the Image yield different results?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the transformation from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$.  With the matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\quad 1
\\
0\quad 1
\\
2\quad 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
According to what people write on Stack overflow all I need is to reduce the matrix and then take the columns which have a leading number there. So here I gotta take both columns and get. $(102), (111)$ being the basis and $\dim(\operatorname{Im})=2$.

Point is, I read a book now. They do it in a different way.  They reduce the matrix by adding a third column of $a,b,c$.  And then when reducing they find the image.  Then they get the basis equals  $(102) , (011)$.

These are different results.   Maybe their span provides the same plane?? I am not sure. That's why I am asking.   They have same dim but what tells me they are the same thing?  When I compare the two they don't seem at all to be equal. 
I need help if someone can clarify what's going on here.

Comment: The spans are different. Could you provide the other solution? Otherwise we cannot say where is the difference

Comment: Can you please first say what is the correct one?  Is my solution correct? The way they go is by adding a,b,c as a third collom cuz they say every vector on the Image is some (a,b,c). Then when reducing all colloms to gather with (a, b,c) you get after a few steps that c-2a+b=0 and this is the image.  If you play with it. They get the basis equals  (011), (1,0,2)

Comment: The first solution is the correct one.

Comment: First, I find it surprising that you even got a reaction in overflow. There is research level and usually questions like this are sent over here. Second, it is **always** true that the image of the matrix is spanned by its columns. That "adding a third column" makes no sense at all **unless** they want to know whether the vector represented by that third column is spanned by the first two ones, a different (though related) problem

Comment: Don Antonio?  Why not? Getting two different results seems to me reasonable for being posted on stack overflow.  Also, their solution does make sense cuz every vector on the image is represented by some (a,b,c) which is equal to the matrix multiple by some (x, y). Once you reduce it you get some equations which can be understood as conditions for Image.  Then you play with it and get their result.

Comment: Paolo.  Thx for your informative comments.  I still don't get what's wrong with their way. But at least I know my result is correct.  Thx.

Comment: @bengy Read my *whole* comment: it makes no sense **at all** to add any third column **if** you only want to know what the image of the matrix is: you only need the matrix's columns, that's all. Now , if you want to know whether a column vector **is** in the span of the columns then you can add that third column and reduce (by columns). It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: It makes perfect sense.  It's just a longer way.  But it explains why it's correct as opposed to just saying 'colloms can span' this way makes it clear why it's correct.   And I got the answer.  In the book there was supposed to be 'minus ' one. The minus was omitted or faded somehow.   It works fine cuz they do get the same span.